# Typescript Type Definition in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I am running into an issue where types installed with npm using @types are appearing as suggestions in Intellisense but then receive the error "Cannot find name type."

As an example, I am using nodemailer and have also installed the type definitions for it. When I don't explicitly state the type it is being detected correctly ( I am hovering over "transporter" which is identified correctly as Mail):

[image]

When I am typing it also correctly suggests the type in Intellisense:

[image]

However, once I finish explicitly stating the type I receive an error:

[image]

I am not declaring the typeRoot in the tsconfig as it is using the default structure available since TS2 and @types.

```
 {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "CommonJs"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can explicitly define variable types that are using types from @types?